# $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be injective then $f^{ −1} (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1])$ is

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be injective then $f^{ −1} (\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1])$ is

(a) measurable and its measure is 0.

(b) measurable and its measure is 1.

(c) measurable and its measure is ∞.

(d) need not be measurable.

totally clueless, please help. I know  that $[0,1],\mathbb{Q}$ are borel measurable and hence their intersection, also they are lebesgue measurable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is countable, and $f$ is one-to-one, you have that $f^{-1}(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1])$ is countable as well. Hence: measurable and of measure ...

Comment: $000000000000000000$

Comment: @TaxiDriver: well, it depends on the measure. Which is unspecified in your question ;)